# `require': cannot load such file -- mysql(LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

when I use mysql in ruby script occurred LoadError.the detail info is below:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from data.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I have installed mysql2 (0.3.17) gem. And I use this [script](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box/blob/master/bootstrap.sh) to build my ruby environment.

Comment: Please install gem `mysql`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `mysql2` gem, you need to

```
require 'mysql2'
```

instead of

```
require 'mysql'
```

which would work if you'd installed the `mysql` gem.